# Poppler + Rails gives me an error on M1 Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, homebrew, poppler

App I am working on has Poppler as a gem.  When I try to run the rails server after `bundle install` I get the following;

```
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler/loader.rb:93:in `define_struct': 
uninitialized constant Poppler::Loader::Action (NameError)
```

And I'm completely stuck.

I have attempted to `brew install poppler` which seemed to work fine, but the error is the same.  All of my gems are up to date.  My OS is up to date.

Others in my company aren't having this issue.

I'm terrible at solving this sort of things.. thoughts?

And to be through here is a complete error dump from `rails s` to exit:

```
(NULL)-WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libpoppler-glib.8.dylib' referenced by the typelib: dlopen(libpoppler-glib.8.dylib, 9): image not found
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:561:in `load_union_info'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:74:in `load_info'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:43:in `block in load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `times'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `block in each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:42:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:27:in `<module:Poppler>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(NULL)-WARNING **: Failed to load shared library 'libpoppler.111.dylib' referenced by the typelib: dlopen(libpoppler.111.dylib, 9): image not found
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:561:in `load_union_info'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:74:in `load_info'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:43:in `block in load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `times'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `block in each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:42:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:27:in `<module:Poppler>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:22:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/activesupport-6.1.3.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
Traceback (most recent call last):
    54: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    53: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    52: from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    51: from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    50: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
    49: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `load'
    48: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    47: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    46: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    45: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    44: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/spring-2.1.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    43: from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    42: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    41: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    40: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    39: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    38: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    37: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    36: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
    35: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    34: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    33: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    32: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/thor-1.1.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    31: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
    30: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `tap'
    29: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/railties-6.1.3.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `block in perform'
    28: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    27: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    26: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    25: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    24: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    23: from /Users/me/Sites/ambiki/config/application.rb:7:in `<main>'
    22: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:173:in `require'
    21: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `require'
    20: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:50:in `each'
    19: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `block in require'
    18: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
    17: from /Users/me/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    16: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
    15: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    14: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    13: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    12: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/bootsnap-1.7.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
    11: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:22:in `<main>'
    10: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler.rb:27:in `<module:Poppler>'
     9: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:42:in `load'
     8: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
     7: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:32:in `each'
     6: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `block in each'
     5: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:33:in `times'
     4: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/repository.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in each'
     3: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:43:in `block in load'
     2: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:60:in `load_info'
     1: from /Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/gobject-introspection-3.4.4/lib/gobject-introspection/loader.rb:137:in `load_struct_info'
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.3/gems/poppler-3.4.4/lib/poppler/loader.rb:93:in `define_struct': uninitialized constant Poppler::Loader::Action (NameError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after days of fighting with it. There is a weird homebrew issue (I think) where it installs the libraries required for poppler at `/opt/homebrew/lib/` but it after digging it needs to be `/usr/local/lib/`  so a couple sim links later, it appears to be running now..